# Setting Validation rules to multiple fields using VBA code returns error 3309 (too large)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to ask you for help with (edited) VBA code I found while searching for solution. My goal is to add validation rule to multiple field of table at once by VBA code. I have to use VBA code because there is so many fields and manual input would be insane.
Validation rule: **NOT LIKE "*"+Chr(10)+"*" OR "*"+Chr(13)+"*" OR "*"+Chr(9)+"*"**
(user can't save "enter", "ctrl+enter" and "tabulator")
For using this rule in VBA function the syntax is quite different but input to MS Access is correct.

My VBA code (not directly my, I found it and edit to my needs)

```
Public Function SetFieldValidation()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strValidRule As String
Dim strValidText As String
Dim bytNumOfFields As Byte

strValidRule = "NOT LIKE " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & "+Chr(10)+" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " OR " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & "+Chr(13)+" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " OR " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & "+Chr(9)+" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34)
strValidText = "Some error msg"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("Table_Name")

For bytNumOfFields = 0 To tdf.Fields.Count - 1
  With tdf.Fields(bytNumOfFields)
    If .Name <> "Record ID" Then
      .ValidationRule = strValidRule
      .ValidationText = strValidText
    End If
  End With
Next
End Function
```

In the past this script works with rule **NOT LIKE "*"+Chr(10)+"*" OR "*"+Chr(13)+"*"**.
Than tried to add **OR "*"+Chr(9)+"*"**.
Since this modification the MS Access (VBA) returns error: **Property value is too large. (Error 3309)** while I run the script. When I tried return to previous version of script without +Chr(9)+, the error still remains (even I succesfully used this script in the past and validation rules are set in another tables).

I'm really beginer in VBA, honestly I only need to setup this rule to all field of all tables. Can someone experienced tell me what's wrong in the code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code shows `"+Chr(10)+"`, but your narrative shows `"*"+Chr(10)+"*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using `Chr()`.  Since `Chr` will always return the same value for a particular number, e.g. `Chr(65)` always returns `A`, I don't think you need to use the function to get the value you want.  So try setting your `strValidRule` as one long static string with the characters returned by the `Chr()` functions hard coded.

Comment: Thank you for advice but I'm little bit confused. I need this function to add valid rules to all fields (ca 150 in some tables, not my design) in nearly 40 tables. So I just use this function in each table. I tried to use NOT LIKE "*"+Chr(10)+"*" OR "*"+Chr(13)+"*" directly in code but my problem are quotes ". They are used for string value syntax as borders but they are also inside the string, and I donť know how to escape quotes inside string, so I found solution with Chr(34) which is symbol " and made a string from it. If there is better solution, please, let me know.

Comment: Are there values you're trying to exclude that are literally "+chr(13)+" in the relevant fields?  It looked to me like you were using the `chr()` function in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Rominus I found out the approach with ""*"" I didn't know it in the past so that's why I used chr(34). But the error msg were still shown after running script. More info is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a research and probably the problem is somewhere else - looks like error in table design of specific table.
1.) **First test:** At first I tried to debug `strValidRule` string and compare two approaches for string (my and with quotes as @Rominus advised). The results are same but `quoString` is smoother approach. Than I run script (tried both approaches). Error msg said *'Property Value Too Large'* error 3309 and the old valid rules remains in table design **unchanged** (rules were set in the past and remains).

```
Sub teststring()
    chrString = "chrString: NOT LIKE " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " +Chr(10)+ " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " OR " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " +Chr(13)+ " & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34)
    Debug.Print chrString
    quoString = "quoString: NOT LIKE ""*"" +Chr(10)+ ""*"" OR ""*"" +Chr(13)+ ""*"""
    Debug.Print quoString
End Sub
```

2.) **Second test:** From my script above I firstly 'commented' values of `strValidRule` and `strValidText` by `'` and add empty values `""`. Script run without error msg and added empty values.
Than I 'uncommented' the values and run script with values mentioned above (`quoString` approach and some msg for `strValidText`). Scritp run with error msg *'Property Value Too Large'* error 3309. BUT, when I checked table design, the valid rules were **properly set and working** even the error msg popped up.

3.) **Third test:** I tried to use script in **another** table and run it **without** previously adding empty values described in step 2. (because in table were set old valid rules too). Script **successfully overwrote old valid rules by new ones without msg of error 3309.**

So, I found the way how to set valid rules but there is still some bug that shows error msg in specific table. Don't know how to fix it but I hope it haven't affect of my main goal (setting new working valid rules).